# About BigQuery Date_diff vs Excel DateDif

Tags: google-bigquery

Start Date = 08/25/2006 , End Date = 06/22/2020 , "Y"

Results diff.

Excel Datedif = 13 Years (Expected Result)

BigQuery Date_diff = 14 Years

Does Anyone can help a query on BigQuery such same result on Excel ?

Answer (score 0):

It is doing as instructed (i.e. counting the difference between `years` of both dates). However, for a "technically" right answer, you can try this:

```
select cast(
    floor(
        (date_diff(parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', '06/22/2020'), 
        parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', '08/25/2006'), day)) / 365
    ) as int64
)
```

Comment: but it is not work for 6/21/2006 to 6/20/2020

Answer (score 0):

Share your exact query for future questions. In this case though I suspect you are using a query of sort

```sql
     SELECT 
       
            (DATE_DIFF(PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', '06/22/2020'), 
            PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', '08/25/2006'), YEAR)) years_diff
```

which just computes the difference in years 2006 and 2020.

Instead if you want to be more precise and simulate excel's behavior of calculating number of complete years(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38) there seems to be no out of the box way to do this. Instead you can use the following custom function to do this, Can also be done using a switch case but bundling it into a function keeps it clean. Calculating number of days and dividing by `365` wouldn't work because of leap years and similarly calculating `months` wont work when target and source dates are from same `month`

```sql
DEFINE MACRO extract_date_part EXTRACT($3 FROM PARSE_DATE($1, $2));
    
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getCompleteYears(
      date_string_1 STRING, date_string_2 STRING, date_format_string STRING)
    RETURNS INT64 AS (
      IF( $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_2,MONTH)> $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_1,MONTH), /* month 2 > month 1 */
          $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_2,YEAR)- $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_1,YEAR),
            IF($extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_2,MONTH)< $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_1,MONTH),/* month 2 < month 1 */
                  $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_2,YEAR)- $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_1,YEAR)-1,
                     IF($extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_2,DAY)< $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_1,DAY),/* if month 2 = month 1, compare day */
                         $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_2,YEAR)- $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_1,YEAR)-1,
                         $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_2,YEAR)- $extract_date_part(date_format_string, date_string_1,YEAR)
                         )
               )
      )
    );
    
    SELECT  getCompleteYears('06/21/2006','07/20/2020','%m/%d/%Y') as num_of_complete_years
     ;
```

Comment: Expected Result = 13 , not 14.
Using BigQuery can`t get 13.

Comment: Made some edits based on your sample inputs, should work now! Good luck!